# Need help separating the contents of a variable into 2 varaibles in python

Tags: python-3.x

So i have a string variable that looks like this:

```
text = "('127.0.0.1', 64069)"
```

I want to separate the ip address into a variable called HOST and the port into another variable called PORT.

I tried this to clean up the unessisary chars:

```
x = text.replace(',', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace("'", "")
```

It's sloppy looking but it works, Right now im just stuck trying to figure out how to go about separating the IP and the PORT into 2 separate variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(text)
('127.0.0.1', 64069)
>>> host, port = ast.literal_eval(text)
>>> host
'127.0.0.1'
>>> port
64069
```

Comment: Wow. The answer was so simple... Thanks Ignacio!